# Adding features to Maze Solver java program

Tags: java

I'm writing a maze solver program in java and I'm having trouble figuring out how to add certain features. Right now I have it working for a 2D char array that I hard coded.

I need buttons that can:

1. load a maze (that the user can select) from a text file and place it into the 2D char array.
2. start the maze (basically a button that starts the solveMaze() method in MazeApp.java)

A scrollbar that can control the value in Thread.sleep() that is inside the solveMaze method.

And a text field that can display what is (or isn't) going on with the maze (i.e. "no maze loaded", "maze loaded", "solution in progress", "found finish at this point: ")

MazeApp that handles the GUI:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MazeApp extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    final private int cellSize = 20; // how big the cells/squares are
    final private int rows = 25; // how many rows are in the array (need to be able to get this info from txt file)
    final private int cols = 25; // how many columns are in the array (need to be able to get this info from txt file)
    private boolean mazeSolved = false; // boolean to check if maze is solved
    private boolean solutionExists = true;
    private int startLocX, startLocY; // ints used for '@' start location
    int cellLocX, cellLocY; // cell location that moves through the maze

//    private char[][] easyMaze = {
//            {'#','#', '#', '#', '#'},
//            {'#','@', '.', '.', '#'},
//            {'#','#', '#', '.', '#'},
//            {'#','.', '.', '.', '#'},
//            {'#','#', '#', '#', '#'},
//            {'-','-', '-', '-', '-'},
//            {'#','#', '#', '#', '#'},
//            {'#','=', '.', '.', '#'},
//            {'#','#', '#', '.', '#'},
//            {'#','*', '.', '.', '#'},
//            {'#','#', '#', '#', '#'},
//    };

    //hard coded example 1 level maze with multiple finishes;
    private char[][] easyMaze = {
            {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','.','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','.','#','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','.','#','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','.','#'},
            {'#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','.','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#'},
            {'#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#','#','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','.','.','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
            {'#','.','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#'},
            {'#','@','#','.','#','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','.','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#'},
            {'#','.','.','.','#','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','.','#','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','*','#'},
            {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}
    };

    // goes through array and paints cells
    public void paintComponent(Graphics myGrfx) {

        super.paintComponent(myGrfx);

        //for loop to paint the rows
        for(int i = 0;  i < rows; i++){

            //for loop to paint the cols
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (i == cellLocX && j == cellLocY) {
                    myGrfx.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    myGrfx.fillRect(j * cellSize, i * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                } else if (easyMaze[i][j] == '#') {
                    myGrfx.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    myGrfx.fillRect(j * cellSize, i * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                } else if (easyMaze[i][j] == '*') {
                    myGrfx.setColor(Color.RED);
                    myGrfx.fillRect(j * cellSize, i * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                } else if (easyMaze[i][j] == '.') {
                    myGrfx.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    myGrfx.fillRect(j * cellSize, i * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                } else if (easyMaze[i][j] == 'x') {
                    myGrfx.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    myGrfx.fillRect(j * cellSize, i * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                } else if (easyMaze[i][j] == '=') {
                    myGrfx.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    myGrfx.fillRect(j * cellSize, i * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // goes through the array to find '@', starts start locations points at i and j
    public void getStartPosition() {
        for(int i = 0;  i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (easyMaze[i][j] == '@') {
                    startLocX = i;
                    startLocY = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void getStairsPosition() {
        for(int i = 0;  i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (easyMaze[i][j] == '=') {
                    startLocX = i;
                    startLocY = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // marks visited paths with an 'x', shaded light gray
    public void markPath(int locX, int locY){
        easyMaze[locX][locY] = 'x';
        cellLocX = locX;
        cellLocY = locY;
    }

    // method you have to use for threads, need to replace with timer stuff
    public void run() {
        getStartPosition();
        solveMaze(startLocX, startLocY);
    }

    // checks to see if the maze has found an exit
    public boolean isFinished(int locX, int locY) {
        if (easyMaze[locX][locY] == '*') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // boolean that checks for walls
    public boolean outOfBounds(int locX, int locY) {
        if (easyMaze[locX][locY] == '#') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // boolean to check if a cell has been visited
    public boolean haveVisited(int locX, int locY) {
        if (easyMaze[locX][locY] == 'x') {

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void noSolution() {
        for(int i = 0;  i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (easyMaze[i][j] == '#' || easyMaze[i][j] == 'x') {
                    solutionExists = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // method that calls itself and checks for finish, walls, or already visited paths
    private void solveMaze(int locX, int locY) {
        if (isFinished(locX, locY)) {
            mazeSolved = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Yay, we found the finish!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (outOfBounds(locX, locY)) {
            return;
        }

        if (haveVisited(locX, locY)) {
            return;
        }

        if (!mazeSolved) {
            markPath(locX, locY);
            repaint();
            try {Thread.sleep(50); } catch (Exception e) { }

            solveMaze(locX, locY+1); // move right
            solveMaze(locX + 1,locY); // move down
            solveMaze(locX - 1, locY); // move up
            solveMaze(locX, locY - 1); // move left
        }
    } // end solveMaze
} // end class
```

This is the test class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MazeTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame maze = new JFrame();
        maze.setSize(750, 520);
        maze.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        maze.setTitle("Maze Solver 1.0");
        MazeApp myMazeApp = new MazeApp();
        maze.setContentPane(myMazeApp);
        maze.setVisible(true);
        Thread myThread = new Thread(myMazeApp);
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific about the help you are after. Assuming you don't want someone to write the code to add those features, exactly where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to `MazeApp` should do the trick:

```
private static final int initialSpeed = 50;
private static final int paddingTop = 30;
private static final int paddingLeft = 30;
private JButton loadMazeBtn = new JButton("Load Maze");
private JButton runMazeBtn = new JButton("Run Maze");
private JScrollBar speedBar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
private JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("Starting up...");

private void add(JComponent component, int x, int y) {
    add(component);
    component.setLocation(x, y);
    component.setSize(component.getPreferredSize());
}

public MazeApp() {
    setLayout(null);

    int x = cols * cellSize + paddingLeft;
    int y = paddingTop;

    add(loadMazeBtn, x, y);
    add(runMazeBtn, x, y + 40);
    add(speedBar, x, y + 80);
    add(statusLabel, x, y + 120);

    loadMazeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Fill in your code to load the maze
        }
    });

    runMazeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Fill in your code to run the maze
        }
    });

    speedBar.setValue(initialSpeed);
}

// Call this method when you want to change the status text
// (i.e. "no maze loaded", "maze loaded", "solution in progress", "found finish at this point: ")
public void setStatusText(String text) {
    statusLabel.setText(text);
}

// Call this function to feed the Thread.sleep
public int getSpeed() {
    return speedBar.getValue();
}
```

You just need to fill in your code for the "load maze" and "run code", and add calls to `setStatusText` whenever the status changes.

For the "speed bar" change the `Thread.sleep` code in `solveMaze` to

```
Thread.sleep(getSpeed());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't figure out how to add JButtons for the way I had this setup.

Comment: I'm having a problem with the maze responding to the start button. I take out the solveMaze(startLocX, startLocY) out of the run method and just put it inside the start method.

The program runs and places the cell at the starting position and DOES solve the maze, but once I hit start it doesn't actually show the animation and it won't let me control the thread scroll.

Comment: @user2275834 This is because the code specified in the button's actionPerformed method is executed in the EventThread. I.e. your routine `solveMaze` is executed in the EventThread, thus blocking it until the maze is solved. This way the system has no chance to refresh the screen, something that is typically done in the EventThread. To solve this keep the `solveMaze(startLocX, startLocY)` at its original location in the `run` routine. In the start button's `actionPerformed` method put the code from you MazeTest class that starts the maze (`Thread myThread = new Thread(MazeApp.this);...`)